# Stored procedure is giving an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure on SQL Server 2008, I get an error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_UpdateDistribiutionList,
>   Line 12 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Can you advise?

**Stored procedure code:**

```
USE LogDB
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UpdateDistribiutionList 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@distId INT,
@DistEmails varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [NotificationDistribution] AS dist
SET dist.emailCC = @DistEmails
WHERE dist.DistributionID = @distId
END
```

2nd question:

is it possible to use parameter to get column name like dist.@columnName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your UPDATE to the following:

```
UPDATE [NotificationDistribution]
SET emailCC = @DistEmails
WHERE DistributionID = @distId
```

If you want to do it Dynamic:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UpdateDistribiutionList 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@distId INT,
@DistColumn varchar(max),
@DistValue varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN


    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQL = 
    N'UPDATE [NotificationDistribution]
    SET ' + QuoteName(@DistColumn ) + ' = @DistValue 
    WHERE DistributionID = @distId'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql 
    @SQL,
    N'@DistValue  varchar(max), @distId INT',
    @DistValue  = @ColumnValue,
    @distId = @distId

END
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `AS` in the `UPDATE` statement, and put it in the `FROM` clause instead, it should be:

```
UPDATE dist
SET dist.emailCC = @DistEmails
FROM [NotificationDistribution]  AS dist
WHERE dist.DistributionID = @distId
```

---

For your second question, you can't do this like that, you have to do this dynamically using dynamic SQL.